# How to make a CheckBox unselectable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering how you make a `CheckBox` unselectable in c#?  I thought it would be something like SetSelectable (false) or something but I can't seem to see the method.

I found `CanSelect` but this seems to be a read only property.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the `Enabled` property to `false`:

```
checkBox1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: This will disable the label too, graying it out. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5961238/1633924) is better

Answer (score 144):

You can set [AutoCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.autocheck.aspx) property to `false`.

Comment: @bunggo - Agreed, why are the simplest solutions sometimes the hardest to find...

Comment: A user should be able to see without elaboration whether she will be able to check the box or not.

Comment: This resolved tooltip not visible when checkbox was not enabled, used AutoCheck = false instead Enabled = false

Comment: This is a great solution, never found out about this hidden property until now. This is really a missing piece when it comes to checkboxes. `Enable = False` if often not a good solution, it really makes the checkbox difficult to read. Disabling is useless for read-only mode, as it is not allowing to physically read the text!

Comment: How did i never know about this!

Answer (score 8):

You can create one by using following code

```
public class ReadOnlyCheckBox : System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
{
        private bool readOnly;

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
                // pass the event up only if its not readlonly
                if (!ReadOnly) base.OnClick(e);
        }

        public bool ReadOnly
        {
                get { return readOnly; }
                set { readOnly = value; }
        }
}
```

or also you can handle the checked change event and always set it back to value you want

Comment: Seems a little elaborate when Enabled will suffice.

Comment: I thought disabling won't look nice because it will disable the text as well

Comment: @HarisHasan in which case go with Jacob Seleznev's answer - use AutoCheck to disable check/uncheck without disabling the text

Comment: Right, AutoCheck does the exact same thing without creating a new class

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a more read-only behavior:

- Disable highlight when the cursor is over the `CheckBox`
- Disable reacting (logically or visibly) to a mouse click
- Have tooltips enabled

We can inherit the `CheckBox` class (similar to [Haris Hasan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5961147/10927863) but with some improvements):

```
public class ReadOnlyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Category("Behavior")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; } = false;

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable highlight when the cursor is over the CheckBox
        if (!ReadOnly) base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable reacting (logically or visibly) to a mouse click
        if (!ReadOnly) base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Suppress space key to disable checking/unchecking 
        if (!ReadOnly || e.KeyData != Keys.Space) base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Enabled` property to `false`

Answer (score 0):

For disabling all the checkboxes in a `CheckedListBox`

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxChecks.Items.Count; i++)
{
   checkedListBoxChecks.SetItemChecked(i, true);
   //checkedListBoxChecks.Enabled = false;
   this.checkedListBoxChecks.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);                  
}


private void checkedListBoxChecks_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
    {
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoCheck doesn't exist in UWP but I think you can use IsTapEnabled = false.

Answer (score 0):

In response to some comments about grayed out label: Set the `Text` of the `CheckBox` to the empty string, `Enable`to `false` and use a `Label` for the text.

Drawback: No mnemonic support out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage a simple `Label` using a glyph like this for its `Text`: `✔ checkBox1`.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
public class CtrlCheckBoxReadOnly : System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
{
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ReadOnly) base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```