# Read-only (visually) CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I need to have 2 groups of controls on the screen: **inputs** and **outputs** (so they have 2 states: *On* or *Off*). Thus `CheckBox` seems to be a good choice. Checking any **output** will set it.

However, when displaying **inputs** there will be no user interaction with it. User is only allowed to see its value, not to change it.

### Question: how to make checkbos visually appears as *read-only* ?

Could think about possible solutions:

- Make `CheckBox` disabled. Bad: there will be no tooltip (possible to solve it? by fake panel on top?) and visually disabled `CheckBox` is not nice (and I don't want to make user think it is *disabled*).
- Use different control. Which one? `Label` doesn't have nice placeholder for the On/Off value. `RadioButton` look differently, but they usually means there is a single choice out of many, while values of **inputs** are independent.
- Making own component. Drawing the whole `CheckBox` is a bit overkill (and honestly, I don't know how to do it to have Win7 appearance). Would it be possible to add only `ReadOnly` appearance to the box part easily?

What do you guys think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a checkbox unselectable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961104/how-to-make-a-checkbox-unselectable)

Comment: @CodeCaster, my question is different. I know how to prevent user from *using* the control, but it is still visually the same *ready to be clicked checkbox*. And this is my problem, to display to the user that *sorry, but I am read-only checkbox*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to draw everything yourself. I think you should use some controls with correct layout to mimic it. Here is the demo code for you, note that it **does not** support `AutoSize` correctly. Because the drawn stuff is always wider than the default stuff (which the `AutoSize` works with), implementing the `AutoSize` is not easy, If you don't care too much about `AutoSize`, this would be the great control for you:

```
public class XCheckBox : CheckBox
{        
    public XCheckBox()
    {            
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, false);
        ReadOnlyCheckedColor = Color.Green;
        ReadOnlyUncheckedColor = Color.Gray;
    }        
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    public bool AlwaysShowCheck { get; set; }
    public Color ReadOnlyCheckedColor { get; set; }
    public Color ReadOnlyUncheckedColor { get; set; }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        if (ReadOnly)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            pevent.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            if (AlwaysShowCheck || Checked)
            {
                RenderCheck(pevent.Graphics);
            }
            RenderText(pevent.Graphics);                
        }
        else base.OnPaint(pevent);                            
    }
    private void RenderCheck(Graphics g)
    {
        float fontScale = Font.Size / 8.25f;   
        Size glyphSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(g, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);            
        glyphSize.Width = (int) (glyphSize.Width * fontScale);
        glyphSize.Height = (int)(glyphSize.Height * fontScale);            
        string checkAlign = CheckAlign.ToString();
        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Checked ? ReadOnlyCheckedColor : ReadOnlyUncheckedColor, 1.5f)
        {
            LineJoin = LineJoin.Round,
            EndCap = LineCap.Round,
            StartCap = LineCap.Round
        })
        {
            gp.AddLine(new Point(3, 7), new Point(5, 10));
            gp.AddLine(new Point(5, 10), new Point(8, 3));
            float dx = checkAlign.EndsWith("Right") ? Math.Max(-4*fontScale, ClientSize.Width - glyphSize.Width - 4 * fontScale) :
                     checkAlign.EndsWith("Center") ? Math.Max(-4*fontScale, (ClientSize.Width - glyphSize.Width) / 2 - 4 * fontScale) : -4;
            float dy = checkAlign.StartsWith("Bottom") ? Math.Max(-4*fontScale, ClientSize.Height - glyphSize.Height - 4*fontScale) :
                     checkAlign.StartsWith("Middle") ? Math.Max(-4*fontScale, (ClientSize.Height - glyphSize.Height) / 2 - 4*fontScale) : 0;

            g.TranslateTransform(dx, dy);
            g.ScaleTransform(1.5f*fontScale, 1.5f*fontScale);
            g.DrawPath(pen, gp);
            g.ResetTransform();                
        }
    }
    private void RenderText(Graphics g)
    {
        Size glyphSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(g, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);
        float fontScale = Font.Size / 8.25f;
        glyphSize.Width = (int)(glyphSize.Width * fontScale);
        glyphSize.Height = (int)(glyphSize.Height * fontScale);
        string checkAlign = CheckAlign.ToString();
        using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
        {
            string alignment = TextAlign.ToString();
            sf.LineAlignment = alignment.StartsWith("Top") ? StringAlignment.Near :
                               alignment.StartsWith("Middle") ? StringAlignment.Center : StringAlignment.Far;
            sf.Alignment = alignment.EndsWith("Left") ? StringAlignment.Near :
                           alignment.EndsWith("Center") ? StringAlignment.Center : StringAlignment.Far;
            sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
            Rectangle textRectangle = ClientRectangle;
            if (checkAlign.EndsWith("Left"))
            {
                textRectangle.Width -= glyphSize.Width;
                textRectangle.Offset(glyphSize.Width, 0);
            }
            else if (checkAlign.EndsWith("Right"))
            {
                textRectangle.Width -= glyphSize.Width;
                textRectangle.X = 0;
            }
            g.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), textRectangle, sf);
        }
    }        
    bool suppressCheckedChanged;
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReadOnly) {
            suppressCheckedChanged = true;
            Checked = !Checked;
            suppressCheckedChanged = false;
        }
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
    protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (suppressCheckedChanged) return;
        base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
    }        
}
```

**NOTE**: The code is not fully implemented, everything is kept as simple as possible. You can change the `AlwaysShowCheck` property to choose the `ReadOnly` unchecked state, it can be a *gray tick mark* or *nothing*. You can set the `ReadOnly` to `true` to make it *Read-only visual*.

`AlwaysShowCheck` is set to `true` (the ReadOnly unchecked state is indicated by a gray tick mark)

[image]

`AlwaysShowCheck` is set to `false` (the ReadOnly unchecked state is indicated by nothing)

[image]

Comment: I have feeling, you just share one of your own used components. Thanks. Tested it, it works pretty fine. Tooltips are working, style can be tuned. `AutoSize` is [indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308883/groupbox-autosize) [very](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088322/label-userpaint-drawn-text-doesnt-fit) [tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337421/groupbox-autosize-and-groupbox-text-wrapping)

Comment: @Sinatr in fact it's not my own used component, I've just written it when attempting to answer your question. I want all the future projects of mine will use `WPF`, not `winforms`, the customization is much easier, however if the team use `winforms`, I still have to use it.

Answer (score 15):

There is a solution that is combination of the existing answers.

```
checkBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray; // Read-only appearance
checkBox.AutoCheck = false;      // Read-only behavior

// Tooltip is possible because the checkbox is Enabled
var toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.SetToolTip(checkBox, "This checkbox is read-only.");
```

The result is a `CheckBox` that

- appears disabled with gray text
- prevents the `Checked` value from changing when clicked
- supports a `Tooltip`

Comment: Good catch with `AutoCheck`, disabling it for read-only `CheckBox` is a good idea.

Comment: This should be the correct and accepted answer.  The solution by King King will make it look checked, but the underlying value can change. I believe the OP wanted a checkbox that it's state can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but still can be usefull so here is my solution.

In order to make a read-only behavior:

- Disable highlight when the cursor is over the `CheckBox`
- Disable reacting (logically or visibly) to a mouse click
- Have tooltips enabled

We can inherit the `CheckBox` class and disable mouse and keyboard interaction:

```
public class ReadOnlyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Category("Behavior")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; } = false;

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable highlight when the cursor is over the CheckBox
        if (!ReadOnly) base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable reacting (logically or visibly) to a mouse click
        if (!ReadOnly) base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Suppress space key to disable checking/unchecking 
        if (!ReadOnly || e.KeyData != Keys.Space) base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

In order to make it visually apparent that the `CheckBox` is read-only, we can change the `ForColor` according to the `ReadOnly` property.

Note: changing the `ForColor` only changes the text color, the colors of the checkmark can only be changed by overriding the `OnPaint` method and repainting the `CheckBox` (as far as I know).

Here is an extended version of the previous code that changes the `ForColor` according to the `ReadOnly` property:

```
public class ReadOnlyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    private bool _readOnly = false;
    private Color _readOnlyForeColor = Color.Gray;
    private Color _normalForeColor = Color.Black;

    [System.ComponentModel.Category("Behavior")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get => _readOnly;
        set
        {
            if (_readOnly != value)
            {
                _readOnly = value;
                UpdateForColor();
            }
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.Category("Appearance")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
    public Color NormalForeColor
    {
        get => _normalForeColor;
        set
        {
            if (_normalForeColor != value)
            {
                _normalForeColor = value;
                UpdateForColor();
            }
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.Category("Appearance")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Gray")]
    public Color ReadOnlyForeColor
    {
        get => _readOnlyForeColor;
        set
        {
            if (_readOnlyForeColor != value)
            {
                _readOnlyForeColor = value;
                UpdateForColor();
            }
        }
    }

    // Hide ForeColor from the editor
    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(
        System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get => base.ForeColor;
        set => base.ForeColor = value;
    }

    public ReadOnlyCheckBox()
    {
        UpdateForColor();
    }

    private void UpdateForColor()
    {
        ForeColor = ReadOnly ? ReadOnlyForeColor : NormalForeColor;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable highlight when the cursor is over the CheckBox
        if (!ReadOnly) base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable reacting (logically or visibly) to a mouse click
        if (!ReadOnly) base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Suppress space key to disable checking/unchecking 
        if (!ReadOnly || e.KeyData != Keys.Space) base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing 4th point in your list: make it visually telling "I am read only". Solving "disabled Checkbox with tooltip" is worth upvote from other point.

Comment: I edited the answer and added an extended version of the code that makes the `CheckBox` look read-only by changing the text color to gray.

Answer (score 0):

You may provide a listener for an event of clicking on `CheckBox`, as there's ability to cancel its usual flow at runtime.

Comment: I can easily achieve this by setting `AutoCheckbox = false`. Question is about the *visual appearance*, not events or actions.

Comment: @Sinatr you mean `AutoCheck`, but what's wrong with that? The visual appearance will be exactly the same and user won't be able to change the checkbox state, making it a read-only checkbox. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think OP means to make it look like readonly. As TextBox does with little dull appearance

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yup.

Comment: @Sinatr just give it different background? Readonly textbox get the `SystemColors.Control` color, you can manually set it to your checkbox to get similar appearance.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, interesting idea, thanks. Haven't considered this yet. The only problem is what form has gradient background and most of controls are transparent. Do you think what using `ForeColor` directly (instead of `BackColor`) and making color less *bright* (`Color.Gray`) - will this makes user think what it is *read-only* ?

Answer (score 0):

So far the easiest solution (credits go to ShadowWizard) is to set `ForeColor = Color.Gray`, this makes user think, what `CheckBox` is disabled.

Compared to `Enabled = false`, pluses are:

- `ToolTip` is working;
- box part looks pretty (it react on mouse hovering and is very clearly seen whenever is checked or unchecked).

No minuses.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to write the entire control, just write a derivative of `Checkbox`.

A `ReadOnly` property is added to the control, this causes the control to handle when it can change its value.

```
public class CheckBoxReadOnly : CheckBox
{

    private bool _readOnly = false;
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return _readOnly; }
        set
        {
            if (_readOnly != value)
            {
                _readOnly = value;
                OnReadOnlyChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    int _flag = 0;

    public event EventHandler ReadOnlyChanged;

    protected void OnReadOnlyChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadOnlyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReadOnly)
        {
            _flag++;
            if (_flag == 1)
                Checked = !Checked;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
        }
        _flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A "read-only" visual effect (grey checkbox but black label) can also be achieved using a `CheckBox` without `text` along with a normal `Label` next to it.

Mind that if the `CheckBox` is ever enabled, an `onClick` event would have to be added to the `Label` to mimic the original behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

In the Property table just make selection mode to none.

Comment: could you provide a bit more information with your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Visual studio has now it available under: 
Properties -> Properties -> ReadOnly :)